# $.getJSON returns only one entry

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object

I am using `$.getJSON` and `$.each` to call a JSON end point and retrieve data. When I call the data, I put it in an object and then check it in the console. However, when I check the console, there is only one entry.

Why is only one entry being returned? What am I doing wrong?

[JSON endpoint](https://data.montgomerycountymd.gov/resource/housing-code-enforcement.json)

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5jwotwg7/)

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url =
        'https://data.montgomerycountymd.gov/resource/housing-code-enforcement.json?street_number=9903';
    var myJson = {};
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(i, field) {
            myJson = data;
        });
        console.log(myJson);
    });
});
```

Comment: It's because you're over-writing the `myJson` variable in each iteration. Your `console.log` will only ever show the *last* item in the array. Work with each object *inside* the `$.each` loop.

Comment: @adin What exactly are you trying to do with `myJson` if you just want to copy the received data then surly you don't need to use `each`. Is the received data an array and you want to map it to an object?

Comment: Your endpoint only returns one object, also, it looks like you should be accessing `feild`, not `data` from within your `each` -  http://jsfiddle.net/5jwotwg7/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hell seeing as everyone is repeating themselves thought id get in on the action.

As @RoyMcCrosan said your data value is an array, however your `myJson` variable is an object. What you doing is looping through the array an placing each cell in that array into the `myJson` variable, (here's the important bit), overwriting the value before it. So you end up with only the last value in the array.

Now without knowing what you want to do with the data we can't really say what you should do but here's a few common cases ive had to do:

If you want to simply copy the data and work with it else where as an array simply scrap the `$.each`

```
var myJson = [];
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    myJson = data;
    console.log(myJson);
});
```

If you want to map the data to end up with an array but in a different format:

```
var myJson = [];
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    myJson = data.map(function (d) {
      return {}; //Some modified object
    });
    console.log(myJson);
});
```

If you want to iterate the array and extract a property from each object to add to you `myJson` variable;

```
var myJson = {};
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    data.forEach(function (d) {
       //Some logic for figuring property name.
       var i = 'FieldName';
       myJson[i] = d[i];
    });
    console.log(myJson);
});
```

Finally as `data` is an array using native looping methods such as `.forEach` or a `for` loop. They will be faster then `$.each`. Also technically `myJson` is not JSON its a JavaScript object in its own right.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url =
        'https://data.montgomerycountymd.gov/resource/housing-code-enforcement.json?street_number=9903';
    var myJson = {};
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(i, field) {
            myJson = data;
            console.log(myJson);   
     });

});
```

});

Comment: Ah..dammit. @Rory McCrosan beat me to it!

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your `console.log` statement inside the each iteration, however, please note that your request only returns one JSON document to start with:

```js
    var url =
      'https://data.montgomerycountymd.gov/resource/housing-code-enforcement.json?street_number=9903';
    var myJson = {};
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
      $.each(data, function(i, field) {
        myJson = data;
        document.write(JSON.stringify(myJson, undefined, 2)+'<br>')
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```